# Troubleshooting cmdstanr with high performance computing

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc, stan

I am relatively new to using high performance computing and have been experienceing some issues. I began using my university's hpc to estimate a very large model using cmdstanr. I originally thought it may be due to issues with my code, but I've tried submitting jobs with code that I know 100% works on my personal computer (including example code that one of my professors has used for class) and it yields the same error code. Here is the .job file I've been submitting:

```
#!/bin/bash

#$ -N Growth-Analysis
#$ -cwd
#$ -l localscratch_free=500G

#$ -q UI
#$ -pe smp 4

module load stack/2022.2-base_arch
module load r/4.2.2_gcc-9.5.0
module load cmdstan
module load r-cmdstanr

Rscript argon_pairs.R
```

and here is the error message that is generated:

```
/opt/sge/default/spool/argon-itf-bx47-36/job_scripts/9962836: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/opt/sge/default/spool/argon-itf-bx47-36/job_scripts/9962836: line 8: $'\r': command not found
/opt/sge/default/spool/argon-itf-bx47-36/job_scripts/9962836: line 11: $'\r': command not found
/opt/sge/default/spool/argon-itf-bx47-36/job_scripts/9962836: line 16: $'\r': command not found
This is cmdstanr version 0.5.3
- CmdStanR documentation and vignettes: mc-stan.org/cmdstanr
- CmdStan path: /usr/share/apps/2022.2/base_arch/gcc-9.5.0/cmdstan-2.30.1
- CmdStan version: 2.30.1

A newer version of CmdStan is available. See ?install_cmdstan() to install it.
To disable this check set option or environment variable CMDSTANR_NO_VER_CHECK=TRUE.
Warning: Chain 1 finished unexpectedly!

Warning: Chain 2 finished unexpectedly!

Warning: Chain 4 finished unexpectedly!

Warning: Chain 3 finished unexpectedly!

Warning: Use read_cmdstan_csv() to read the results of the failed chains.
Warning messages:
1: All chains finished unexpectedly! Use the $output(chain_id) method for more information.
 
2: No chains finished successfully. Unable to retrieve the fit. 
Error: No chains finished successfully. Unable to retrieve the draws.
Execution halted
```

Here is one of the .R scripts I ran, in case it helps:

```
library(cmdstanr)

modstan = cmdstan_model(stan_file = "/Users/depy/pairsonly.stan")

modrun = modstan$sample(
    data = "/Users/depy/moddata.json", 
    seed = 789, 
    chains = 4, 
    parallel_chains = 4, 
    iter_warmup = 1000, 
    iter_sampling = 1000
    )

modsum = summary(modrun$draws())

write.csv(modsum, "modsum_growth.csv", row.names = F)
```

Here is the output from the first chain:

```
method = sample (Default)
  sample
    num_samples = 1000 (Default)
    num_warmup = 1000 (Default)
    save_warmup = 0 (Default)
    thin = 1 (Default)
    adapt
      engaged = 1 (Default)
      gamma = 0.050000000000000003 (Default)
      delta = 0.80000000000000004 (Default)
      kappa = 0.75 (Default)
      t0 = 10 (Default)
      init_buffer = 75 (Default)
      term_buffer = 50 (Default)
      window = 25 (Default)
    algorithm = hmc (Default)
      hmc
        engine = nuts (Default)
          nuts
            max_depth = 10 (Default)
        metric = diag_e (Default)
        metric_file =  (Default)
        stepsize = 1 (Default)
        stepsize_jitter = 0 (Default)
    num_chains = 1 (Default)
id = 1 (Default)
data
  file = /Users/depy/moddata.json
init = 2 (Default)
random
  seed = 789
output
  file = /Users/depy/rtemps/pairsonly-202303301233-1-6e07ca.csv
  diagnostic_file =  (Default)
  refresh = 100 (Default)
  sig_figs = -1 (Default)
  profile_file = /Users/depy/rtemps/pairsonly-profile-202303301233-1-09181e.csv
num_threads = 1 (Default)


Gradient evaluation took 2.20088 seconds
1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 22008.8 seconds.
Adjust your expectations accordingly!
```

I originally thought that this issue may be occurring due to cmdstan taking up local memory on the node when writing its temp files. I managed to change the tempdir to point to my personal directory, and that still led to the same error message being thrown. I've reached out to the research computing staff, but I haven't gotten a response back and this issue is a bit time sensitive.

I appreciate any advice - thank you!!